# Opencart web layout is not working on Safari & iPhone properly

Tags: safari, opencart-3

Can anyone tell me that why my opencart layout is not working properly? Sliders are going here and there. Half of my page layout is effected on Safari & iPhone. But in Chrome, Mozila, Opera is fine

Comment: Sorry @K.B. , but I didn't get you. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Safari and Iphone has a lot of problems on browser compatible, so the Apple company should improve his system, but they not bother to improve it. So you should work around to achieve to your shop to work on this system by hiring developers which will improve your shop, or report compatible problems to the Apple.